# Moving one vertex moves all connected vertices

Tags: modeling

Sometimes when I try to move a vertice it moves the triangles around it to. But it won't do it with a certain mesh. How do I make it so when I move the point it moves all the triangles connected to it?

notice how in the first picture I lift it and only one part comes up

but in the second picture all the shapes around it lift up too.
that's what I want to happen

[image][image]

Comment: Please add some images about what you are doing and trying to do, use [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/90348/edit) under your question to add the images and use the tool provide for it.

Comment: Go to Edit mode, select everything by pressing A, press spacebar and type in "Remove doubles" and click that. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have double vertices, you are lifting one, but there is another at the same place. Everything connected to the vertex you are lifting moves with it, but everything connected to the other one doesn't, because you are not moving the vertex.

To solve this problem for one spot, select both vertices (easily done with switching to wireframe mode [Z], and circle select [C]), and merge them into one ([Alt+M]-> At center).[image: Circle select and merge]

If you have  a lot of these doubles, you can solve this for the entire mesh by selecting everything [A], and remove doubles ([Ctrl+V]-> Remove Doubles).[image: Select all and remove doubles]